# Dragon and game high levels

Tags: dragonvale

What are the highest levels you can obtain in DragonVale?
For yourself and for dragons?

Answer (score 2):

The highest level a user can currently reach is 55.  Most dragons can reach a maximum of level 20, but gemstone and epic dragons such as rainbow dragons can reach a maximum of level 10.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the current highest level you can obtain is 55.  Dragons seem to only go up to level 20 as well.

http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Leveling_Rewards
http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Dragons